# ¿Como puedo hacer que un progressbar se reinicie una vez que este se rellene por completo en C#?

Tags: c#, progressbar

Tengo el siguiente codigo, y quiero que cuando llegue al final se reinicie.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        timer1.Start();
        timer1.Interval = 1000;
        progressBar1.Maximum = 10;
        timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
    }

    void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (progressBar1.Value != 10)
        {
            progressBar1.Value++;
        }
        else
        {
            timer1.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿A qué le llamas reiniciar, asignarle el valor en cero? ¿Cuando se detenga el Timer, se tiene que reiniciar su valor o dónde?

Comment: Si a eso me refiero, alguna idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo sería realizar la modificación:

```
void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (progressBar1.Value <= progressBar1.Maximum)
    {
        progressBar1.Value++;
    }
    else
    {
        progressBar1.Value = 0;
        timer1.Stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias, me quedó así al último

Answer (score 1):

Podes hacer algo como:

```
progressBar1.Value = (progressBar1.Value + 1) % progressBar1.Maximum;
```